# csv files don't get updated when web app is hosted on pythonanywhere

Tags: python, csv, flask, pythonanywhere

I have a function in my app.py file, that adds data to the `tracker.csv` file, and there is another function that displays all the values inside the `tracker.csv` file. but it doesn't get updated and nothing is displayed
and If I go to the Web section and hit the 'reload' button the output is displayed.

[image: The tracker.csv has one entry]

when I query the same and try to retrieve the results from the csv I get None
[image]

This us my `app.py` file where I read the csv

```
trackerFile = pd.read_csv('mysite/tracker.csv')
def addData():
   #some operation
   
   df.to_csv('mysite/tracker.csv)
```

there is no problem when I run this webapp on my local machine but it fails to retrieve results when I host it on pythonanywhere.com

Answer (score 0):

`trackerFile = pd.read_csv('mysite/tracker.csv')`

This is at the global level, so the CSV file is only read into `trackerFile` when the python worker is restarted.

You may be able to work around this be loading the file inside a view function.  Something like:

```
@app.route('/some-route')
def addData():
   trackerFile = pd.read_csv('mysite/tracker.csv')
   #some operation
   df.to_csv('mysite/tracker.csv)
```

This means the CSV is read on every request.

**However** you should be aware that this may not scale well under heavy load, as it's accessing the file on every request.  You may wish to look to another storage backend (database/redis/s3) for this.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't provide the results

Comment: Sorry that line needs to be moved to whichever function uses the `trackerFile` var, not `addData`

Comment: Sorry, mahn it still doesn't provide those results I am looking for, the site is not reloading each time I add a data to the csv